# Prevent null values from being displayed on API JSON response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple DTO object like this:

```
        var policyDetails = new PolicyDetailsDto
        {
            PolicyId = policy.Id,
            CustomerId = policy.CustomerId,
            AgentDetails = new AgentDetailsDto
            {
                AgencyName = offices?.MarketingName,
                AgencyPhoneNumbers = new List<string> { offices?.DapPhone, offices?.ContactPhone },
                AgentPhoneNumbers = new List<string> { employees?.BusinessPhone, employees?.HomePhone, employees?.MobilePhone }
            }
        };
```

When I return this dto object from my API to the client, i am getting null values displayed for AgencyPhoneNumbers and AgentPhoneNumbers like this:

```
{
"policyId": "4185a3b8-4499-ea11-86e9-2818784dcd69",
"customerId": "afb2a6e3-37a4-e911-bcd0-2818787e45b7",
"agentDetails": {
    "agencyName": "ABC Agency",
    "agencyPhoneNumbers": [
        "999-666-4000",
         null
    ],
    "agentPhoneNumbers": [
        "5555555555",
        null,
        null
    ]
}}
```

This is the AgentDetailsDto class

```
[JsonObject(ItemNullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public class AgentDetailsDto
{
    public string AgencyName { get; set; }
    public List<string> AgencyPhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public List<string> AgentPhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

How can I prevent null values from showing up in the list in my JSON response?

Comment: Do not add null values to the list or remove them with LINQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore the null values in your WebApiConfig

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = 
                 new JsonSerializerSettings {NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore};
```

if you are using .NET Core you can use this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddMvc()
             .AddJsonOptions(options => {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
     });
}
```